# "Install from web" not working with SSL

Tags: joomla-3.x, security, https

When using Joomla through a secure conection (`https://example.com/administrator`), the *Install from Web* option in the Extension manager gives an error:

> Cannot connect to the Joomla! server. Please try again later.

Google Chrome Developer tools gives the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://appscdn.joomla.org/webapps/index.php?format=json&option=com_apps&view=My3z&dev_level=Ng==&list=grid&pv=MS3wLjU=&callback=jedapps_jsonpcallback'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The error is also reported several times, e.g. [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/4878) and [here](https://github.com/joomla-extensions/install-from-web-client/issues/2), and even said to be solved, but I just confirmed this behavior on several different Joomla 3.3.6 pages on different servers.

Are there any workarounds? Or any particular reason why this still is an issue?

Comment: Super solution, I had thad same problem. Take a look ad your site with firefox and the developer menu ( F12 )
There u can find out ( with the network tab ) witch image had mixed content and is not secure.( enough )
Probably it is your seo tool or page cache that holds an old image.
Firefox makes a list where you can search te problem. Regards Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a (partially) working solution, but it is a core hack, and thus not a good option.

Locate the file `plugins/installer/webinstaller/webinstaller.php`, on change line 21:

```
public $appsBaseUrl = 'http://appscdn.joomla.org/webapps/'; // will be https once CDN is setup for SSL
```

and change it to `https://`:

```
public $appsBaseUrl = 'https://appscdn.joomla.org/webapps/';    // will be https once CDN is setup for SSL
```

The `Install from web` tab will now work, but images still seems to be loaded through a non-secure connection, giving a *Mixed content* error for every image:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://extensionscdn.joomla.org/components/com_example/img/listings/s/40281.png'.
>   This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: It seem that you should create an issue on issues tracker.